# Getting array brackets in magento 2 log

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.0

I am trying to print the log using logger method in magento 2, while printing i am getting 2 empty array brackets in the log. Can anybody say why it happens like this and how to remove those brackets?

sample log response
Coveolog.INFO: {"message":"Source with name 'dss-coveo_m2-integration-b2c-product-en_us' already exists.","errorCode":"INVALID_SOURCE_CONFIGURATION","requestID":"47abdd9f-0ae6-4ed4-a19f-c995d4e62f2c"} **[] []**

Comment: Can you please share code where you are printing

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, look at the class `vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php` which is responsible with writing the log messages. This class implements all the functions to add debug, info, alert, notice, critical or error messages (as per [PSR-3](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-3/)) and they all call the following method:

```php
/**
 * Adds a log record at an arbitrary level.
 *
 * This method allows for compatibility with common interfaces.
 *
 * @param  mixed   $level   The log level
 * @param  string $message The log message
 * @param  array  $context The log context
 * @return bool   Whether the record has been processed
 */
public function log($level, $message, array $context = array())
{
    $level = static::toMonologLevel($level);

    return $this->addRecord($level, $message, $context);
}
```

Say I call the method like this:

`$logger->log('ERROR','my custom error message', [['id'=>'1', 'name' => 'test'], ['var1'=>'value1']]);`

This call will log in `var/log/system.log` the following content:
[2021-04-08 11:52:56

> ] main.ERROR: my custom error message
> [{"id":"1","name":"test"},{"var1":"value1"}] []

I specified the **message level** *ERROR*, the **message** string AND I also printed an array with data also known as **context**. This is very useful when you also want to print which data was used when the error appeared, it helps a lot in the debug process.

As you can see, **the array before last** got populated with the JSON representation of my provided data array. You will also see this in exceptions handling where the exception can be passed as context.

---

As for **the last array**, I didn't see it *in action* so far, but I know it's the **extra** key that we see in `addRecord()` method from `vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php`:

```php
$record = array(
    'message' => (string) $message,
    'context' => $context,
    'level' => $level,
    'level_name' => $levelName,
    'channel' => $this->name,
    'datetime' => $ts,
    'extra' => array(),
);
```

How do I know this? By looking at the class `vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/LineFormatter.php` which is used to format the log lines, where the first thing you see is this:

```php
const SIMPLE_FORMAT = "[%datetime%] %channel%.%level_name%: %message% %context% %extra%\n";
```

Inside the `format()` method of this class, the record's content is processed and formatted and you can see that the *'context'* and *'extra'* keys are prepared to be written in the format given by the `SIMPLE_FORMAT` constant.

So all I can tell about the second array, is that this is the content from **extra** key, but I haven't worked with it, nor see it used so far. If you search for 'extra' in the `vendor/monolog/monolog` you will see other formatters and handlers using it, so there is a use to it, we just didn't see it in action in the logs.